# Can Android play Audible books to a Sonos system?

Tags: audiobooks

I'm considering moving from iPhone to Android in the next couple of months. I'm perfectly happy with the iPhone with one exception - the integration or lack of it between Sonos and Audible apps.

So my question is - with the Android versions of these two apps can I play an audible file through the Sonos app on to my home Sonos kit? I've checked the online docs but they are a little vague and contradictory on the subject.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not so much with the phone as with the connection between sonos and audible. There is currently no service from Sonos to Audible. However, you can connect through the line in on a Play 5 and I think 3 also.  In other words, you play audible through app on phone and plug into the Sonos directly.